# How can we change border color of UIPopoverController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Is there way to change border color of UIPopoverController iPhone/iPad?

Thank you

Comment: here I have another solution quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490261/change-color-navigation-controller-in-a-popover good luck!!!

Answer (score 8):

As of iOS 5, popoverBackgroundViewClass is available which is the only way to do this.

Comment: Hello Can you please tell me how to use popoverBackGroundviewclass ?

Comment: see this article that describes the process of subclassing UIPopoverBackgroundView in detail - [Customizing the design of UIPopoverController](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ios/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller/)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no public way to change the border color of a popover.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is nothing as of yet to change the border color of a uipopover

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible.  Sometimes it makes sense to create your own custom view and graphics and use them instead of a popover.  Of course this depends on how badly you want that custom look.