# How to remove rounded corners in PopoverView?

Tags: ios, xcode, popover, cornerradius

I built a custom Popoverview, but fail to remove the content's rounded corners.

Tried to set `.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0` in almost every view in found, with no success.

Image Link: [Custom Popover](http://www.virtual-hideout.de/_tmp/popover2.png)

Red border is of UIViewController used to init the UIPopoverController with, green is background of custom UIPopoverBackgroundView.

Comment: A screenshot of a problem would help to check what's actually wrong!

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401530/uiview-default-styling-has-rounded-corners

Comment: @Hermang: Can not add image, reputation of 10+ needed :(

Comment: Post the image to something like photobucket / puush then provide a link.

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644149/7113238

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer from this thread: [UIView default styling has rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401530/uiview-default-styling-has-rounded-corners)

> There is no supported way to make the view inside of your UIPopoverController not have rounded corners. The internal code of the UIPopoverController adds your view to a view with rounded corners that clips to bounds.
>
> There may be a hackish way to do it, i.e. waiting until the UIPopoverController is shown and then traversing through all of the parent's of your view and setting them all to have cornerRadius = 0; and clipsToBounds = NO;, but even if you find a solution it might not be compatible with all versions of iOS and if Apple changes some internal code of UIPopoverController in the future then your solution could break.
>
> If you really want to do this then the best way to go is to create your own class that mimics the UIPopoverController functionality.

Comment: have tried this once with no success, but will try again

Comment: Well, you can always create your own view and add the needed functionality to it.

Comment: finally got it to work, built a Custom UIPopoverController with it's own `.presentPopoverFromRect` method that calls `[super presentPopoverFromRect:]` and then set     `self.myViewController.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;`

clipsToBounds=NO seems not to be needed

Comment: @Michael Where did you add the corner radius code to?

Comment: @KyleBegeman in customized UIPopoverController Class method  - (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: @Badrinath sorry, this was a long time ago and I don’t even remember the project I was working on. I should’ve done this.